# Unable to load java class from w3c

Tags: java, ubuntu, w3c, elki, optics-algorithm

I am trying to do OPTICS-clustering with ELKI (http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/).

I try do run the clustering with the provided gui, but then I get this exception:

```
Error in starting visualizer window.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/svg/SVGSVGElement
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.gui.ResultWindow.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.gui.ResultVisualizer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGSVGElement
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.gui.ResultWindow.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.gui.ResultVisualizer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at [...]
```

I unzipped w3c.jar into `/usr/share/java` and into the path of the program. But it still gives me the same error.

I have quite an old Ubuntu (10.04) with OpenJDK version IcedTea6 1.13.3. But I guess that is not was is causing the trouble, right?

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you still have to add that jar into classPath and then it will be recognized.Im not sure what ide you use bud in netbeans for instance rightclick project>libraries>add jar/library.Then your classLoader shoudnt be complaining.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, add w3c.jar into the Java Build Path (it uses the classpath under the hood of course). If you use Java in command line, use "-cp" or "-classpath", it's explained in the manual: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/