# Importing External library in java gives runtime no class found error

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror, beanshell

I am trying to use a beanshell library (bsh.util) which is obviously external. 
Also I have added the jar file to the library.  (By the way I am using netbeans IDE)
But, I don't know why i keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/ConsoleInterface
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.ConsoleInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How you added the library, may be you done some mistake their.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057041/unable-to-load-java-class-from-w3c/24057478#24057478 Might help you.

Comment: I already did the same thing as pointed in Tomas's link. But, somehow it is still complaining. It must be that there is still something missing in the way i added the jar file like afzalex said.

Comment: I was just adding the bsh-util package. But, rather i needed to upload the bsh jar that contains the entire package. I did that and it worked.                                                            Thanks to both afzalex and Tomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just adding the bsh-util-2.0b4.jar -- which is the util package -- from the beanshells library. 
But, rather i needed to upload the bsh jar file that contains the entire package. 
I did that and it worked.

Basically, this is what i did as follows:
1) Downloaded the bsh-2.0b4.jar from http://www.beanshell.org/download.html
2) Added the downloaded bsh-2.0b4.jar to the library through project properties.

Thanks to both afzalex and Tomas.